# Difference between "sétimo" and "séptimo"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

When or where one uses `sétimo` and when/where `séptimo`?

Is it a geographical difference somehow? Is one of them colloquial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the weak pronuntiation of the letter **p** (`séptimo` or `septiembre`) are common mispronounced, so RAE chooses to accept and include this deformed words in the dictionary. Another examples are `octubre` and `otubre`, or `obscuro` and `oscuro`. You can use both versions, however you should be consistent, if you are naming months, said `setiembre y otubre` or `septiembre y octubre`.

Debido a la débil pronunciación de la letra **p** en `séptimo`, los usos y costumbres de "comerse" esa letra al pronunciarlo hacen que la palabra sea aceptada como sinónimo. Lo mismo ocurre con `septiembre` y `setiembre`, incluso con `octubre` y `otubre` o también `obscuro` y `oscuro`. Sucede muy a menudo que la RAE acepte tales deformaciones y las incluya en el diccionario.

Comment: _otubre_ ?? Dios mío que barbaridad. Estos de la RAE se aburren

Comment: @rpax : está marcado como *desusado*.  Pero ten en cuenta que la ciertas combinaciones como *-ct-* o *pt* no son tan naturales en el español (especialmente las de tres consonantes como *-bsc-* o *-mpt-*).  Había muchísima variación en estas palabras en los períodos medieval y áurico, y sigue habiéndola.  Si aceptas «respetar» en vez de «respectar», tienes que entender que este cambio fonético ha sido, y es, más productivo para algunos hablantes que otros.  Si preferirías que volvásemos a escribir (sin pronunciar) todos los grupos de consonantes del latín, pues... todos tendríamos dificultades.

Comment: Muy buena explicación. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

They address exactly the same ordinal number. `Sétimo` has [its own entry in the RAE dictionary](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=kBvpnHQV6DXX2jYJWDDI), and states that is a synonym for `séptimo`.

Variations may depend on regionalisms (some people may find naturally easier to use one over the other, and would do this without even thinking about it), but there are no situations where using one instead of the other would be wrong.

As the entry on the RAE dictionary proves, it is OK to use `Sétimo` in each situation where you would use `Séptimo` and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have cleared the matter good enough, but I can give some context on the use of both words.

At least in Colombia, ommiting the "p" in Septiembre and the "c" in Octubre will give a very bad impression. It is usually associated with uneducated people, even if it is a "correct" word.

I can imagine this being the case in other countries.